# is there a way to use the ggplot aes callout without inputing the column name but by just inputting the column #?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

```
EXAMPLE DATASET:
mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ... 
               ............
```

Recommended ggplot way:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg)) + geom_histogram
```

They way I want to do it:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=[,1]) +geom_histogram
```

or

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=[[1]]))+geom_histogram
```

Why can't ggplot let me call out my variable by its column? I need to call it out by column number not name. Why is ggplot so strict here? Any work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the ggplot `aes` argument evaluates within the data.frame that you pass it. A column name is a string, and can't be properly evaluated the same way.

Fortunately, there is a solution: use the `aes_string` option, as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)

my_data <- mtcars

names(my_data)

ggplot(my_data, aes_string(x=names(my_data)[1]))+
  geom_histogram()
```

This works because `names(my_data)[1]` returns a string, and is perfectly acceptable for the `aes_string` option.

Comment: Thanks. I have a feeling this is a common question with ggplot. Thanks for showing me.